# bios hp proper quality standards

Tags: bios

I keep hp pro desk 400 g3 sff and pc have been run;s on xubuntu 22.04 lts probably 4months without
any problems.

But now pc are not able start. Two long beep ,two short beep.

My question is ,that are any possibility update bios via linux or not.

Thanks for answer

Lukas

Comment: I would create a USB recovery key as described here: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_3966820-3438449-16

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual
[Interactive Beep and LED Diagnostic HP ProDesk 400 G6 DM](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06716795):

> **2 Long, 2 Short**
>
> BIOS in Recovery mode, but no recovery image available.

You will not be able to use the computer without fixing the BIOS.

Get the latest BIOS from the
[HP website](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-prodesk-400-g4-small-form-factor-pc/15292380).
This is an `.exe` file that you need to execute to do the update.

If you can't manage the update yourself, you might need the help of
a professional.